# variable / dynamic content is changing based on <div> -- why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, html, facebox

I have some unexpected behavior in a partial, which is rendered 9 times in users/show.html.erb.  (Visit [www.nowdoing.com/users/2](http://www.nowdoing.com/users/2) to see what I mean.)  Here is the relevant part of the partial (it's verbose for debugging purposes):

```
<%= "object 1 = #{object.content}" %>

<div id="float_have" style="display:none;"> 
   <%= "object 2 = #{object.content}" %>
   <%= render :partial => 'nowposts/floatpost', :locals => { :object => object.content } %>  
</div>

<%= "object 3 = #{object.content}" %>

<a href="#float_have" rel="facebox">Have!</a> |
```

In box #1, :object => "#nowreading book"

In box #2, :object => "#nowlistening song"

Despite this, I'm seeing the following when I load my webpage:

```
 object 1 = "#nowreading book"
 object 2 = "#nowreading book"
 object 3 = "#nowreading book"
```

That makes sense for box#1.  But the following does NOT make sense for box#2:

```
 object 1 = "#nowlistening song"
 object 2 = "#nowreading book"        *** this is wrong
 object 3 = "#nowlistening song"
```

Can someone explain to me why including putting the "#{object.content}" within the facebox DIV causes the content to change?  I find this behavior very peculiar.  Your help is much appreciated!

--- EDIT ---

In users/show.html.erb:

```
            <%= render :partial => 'nowposts/nowpost',
                       :locals => {:object => @nowreading,
                                   :object_link => @reading_link,
                                   :object_mode => "reading",
                                   :doing_img => @reading_img,
                                   :doing_url => @reading_url_text
                                    } %>

            <%= render :partial => 'nowposts/nowpost',
                       :locals => {:object => @nowlistening,
                                   :object_link => @listening_link,
                                   :object_mode => "listening",
                                   :doing_img => @listening_img,
                                   :doing_url => @listening_url_text
                                    } %>
```

In nowposts/_nowpost.html.erb:

```
        <div class ="status bl br">
            Fresh on <%= object.updated_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %><br \>
            <% if user_signed_in? %> 
 <%= "object 1 = #{object.content}" %>
                <div id="float_have" style="display:none;"> 
                    <%= "object 2 = #{object.content}" %>
                    <%= render :partial => 'nowposts/floatpost', :locals => { :object => object.content } %>  

                </div>

                <div id="float_wanna" style="display:none;"> 
                    <%= "object 3 = #{object.content}" %>
                    <%= render :partial => 'wishlists/floatpost', :locals => { :object => object.content } %>  

                </div>  
                <a href="#float_have" rel="facebox">Have!</a> | 
                <a href="#float_wanna" rel="facebox">Wanna!</a> 

            <% end %>
        </div>
```

In application.html.erb:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
          $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
            loadingImage : '../images/loading.gif',
            closeImage   : '../images/closelabel.png'
          })
        })
      </script>
```

The partial nowposts/_floatpoast.html.erb

```
    <h2>Wanna!</h2>
    <h3>You wanna do this?  Great, put it on your bucket list. </h3>

    <%= form_for(:wishlist, :as => @wishlist, :url => {:controller => "wishlists", :action => "create", :user_id => current_user } ) do |f| %>

    <p><%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :content, :value => object, :size => "80" %></p>

      <p><%= f.submit "Post!" %></p>
    <% end %>
```

As mentioned in my comment below, this code was working in my last commit (a few days ago), before I implemented caching of an API result and these nested routes:

```
resources :users 
  resources :nowposts, :only => [:have_create, :create, :new, :show]
end
```

But I don't think that is the problem.  I just ran another test, and object.content only changes when I have it inside this div:

```
  <div id="float_have" style="display:none;">
```

I tried another random div:

```
  <div id="status">
     <%= "object 2 = #{object.content}" %>
  </div>
```

and this displayed correctly. This makes me think that the problem is the Facebox script?  But if so, I wonder why it worked a few days ago.

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Something very fishy about this.  Are you saying that the content of `object.content` changed somehow when it was output a 2nd time?  Is there some relevant code we're not seeing here?  It might help to show the actual code snippets rather than try to summarize, in case you cut out the part which contains the problem.

Comment: Correct -- that is what I am saying.  I will paste the actual code snippets.  Thanks!

Comment: Should be able to tell if it's the facebox script pretty quickly by disabling javascript temporarily.  It's looking like a likely suspect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your code at all, it is too ambiguous. 'object' is a pretty terrible name for a variable, and content is a really bad name for an attribute. Also, your locals for the partial are rendering here doesn't make much sense ({:object => object.content}????). If you would like help, please try to clarify what this means.

That being said, can you change each debug statement from

```
<%= "object 1 = #{object.content}" %>
```

to

```
<%= "object 1 = #{object.inspect}" %>
<%= "object 1 content = #{object.content.inspect}" %>
```

and display the results.

Comment: `object` is a bit awkward here because of the special meaning it (along with `collection`) has with Rails partial views, but I don't see the problem with a `content` attribute.  I do agree the question and code samples could be much clearer, but this is kinda harsh!

Comment: Oh is he trying to just the :object, :as feature of Rails? I thought the correct way to do that was render :partial => 'partial_name', :object => object_instance. Notice the lack of :locals. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Correct, I'm trying to pass the local variable "object.content" to another sub-partial with the name "object".  But let's forget the rendered partial.  I don't believe the problem stems from this, as I once thought.  The immediate problem is that my debug sentence <%= "object 2 = #{object.content}" %> is showing the wrong content, which is then passed to the partial.  Let me edit the question to add something: this was working in my last commit, before I changed the routes to include nested resources.